# PhpStorm crashes on save HDD

Tags: windows, crash, phpstorm

Whenever I edit a file on my HDD with PhpStorm it crashes, yet when I edit a file on my SSD (where the OS is located) it does not crash. To note that Sublime Text or Notepad++ work without any problem (Of course, there is a little delay but no crash)

From what I know, my HDD stops from time to time and starts only when it is required, for example reading files. The is the model: https://www.hgst.com/products/hard-drives/travelstar-5k1000

My guess would be that the reason why it crashes is because it tries to save temporary files or whatever yet the HDD has not started spinning yet which makes the whole program crash.

Is there a way to solve the problem with PhpStorm without not letting my HDD stop?

Comment: I may only suggest to submit a ticket to PhpStorm Issue Tracker -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI -- maybe devs/support team will find some solution/advice (I rarely see JB person answering PhpStorm-specific targeted questions, i.e. not including other JetBrains related tags).

Comment: *"My guess would be that the reason why it crashes is because it tries to save temporary files or whatever yet the HDD has not started spinning yet which makes the whole program crash."* generally speaking such behaviour should not lead to the crash -- I have 1 SSD + 3 HDDs in my box and I see such "app waiting for HDD to wake up" rather often -- none of them crash (no relation to PhpStorm in my case -- even though project files are located on HDD that one never sleeps).

Comment: But since PhpStorm is multi-threaded app that requires fast access to source file (that's why it has some issues when working with files directly over network -- e.g. mounted drive) it could be the reason indeed.

Comment: Okay, I'll try move it there instead, thanks for the help.